# Highcharts: Combined line and column chart - start / end line on left / right side, not on column chart data points

Tags: highcharts

I use column and line charts combination. The problem is that in line chart the leftmost and the rightmost points located in the middle of corresponding bars of column chart. I'd like to extend the line the left / right sides of the chart (look at the thick dark red lines I drawn). Any ideas how to achieve it?

One of the possible solution I found is to add additional data points with null on both sides and then use floor ceiling to "hide" them. It works, but it's a hack I don't like to use, there's should be build it ability to do so..

[image]

Comment: I do not think there is an option for that. If someone does not use steps, where should the line be drawn then? It would require additional points anyway. Adding additional points and setting min and max axis seem to be the easiest way to achieve that result.

Comment: morganfree, look like you are right, 10x

Answer (score 1):

For those who interested in solution with adding additional data points with null here is it. This is the only way I found so far. Pay attention to the line with 'data', 'floor, 'ceiling', 'categories'. But I still think it's a hack and should be build in feature to do so.

```js
// IMPORTANT! Pay attention that fake null data points added
// in order to display targets line correctly, so index 0 = null
config.series[0] = {
  cursor: this.props.onDataPointClick ? 'pointer' : undefined,
  type: 'column',
  data: [null, ...chartData, null],
  pointPadding: 0.01, // to make column full width
  groupPadding: 0, // to make column full width
  dataLabels: {
    enabled: true,
    align: 'center',
    inside: true,
    verticalAlign: 'bottom',
    formatter: function() {
      return humanReadableValue(this.y);
    }
  },
  point: {
    events: {
      click: (e) => this.onDataPointClick(e)
    }
  }
};
Object.assign(config.xAxis, {
  floor: 1,
  ceiling: config.series[0].data.length - 2,
  categories: config.series[0].data.map(x => x === null ? '' : x.name)
});
```

The result

[image]